# Nested mapping in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, mapping

I tried nested mapping in elastic search but it still storing as flattened object. Below are the coding.

```
Mapping
{ "mappings": { 
    "properties": { 
      "Name" : { "type" : "text" }, 
     "Info": { 
     "type": "nested", 
     "properties": 
          { 
             "AccountId" : { "type" : "keyword" },    
             "Address" : { "type" : "keyword" }
 } } } } }

Data
{ "Name" : "xyz", 
"Info" : [ 
           { "AccountId" : "1234", 
             "Address" : "Sm123" 
           },
          { "AccountId " : "5678", 
            "Address" : "Wh235" } ] }


POST http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search

 { "fields": ["*"]}
Output:
Instead of nested output getting single array

" fields":{"Info.AccountId":["1234","5678"]
"Info.Address":["Sm123","Wh235"]
}
```

What is wrong in the mapping file?

Comment: I don't see any issue with your mapping and index data. Can you please share the output of the `GET /<index-name>/_mapping` and have you configured any index template?

Comment: Get ..... /testnested/_mapping
{ "testnested" :{
       "mappings": { 
           "properties": {
                "Info": { 
                      "type": "nested", 
                              "properties":     { 
                                     "Address" : { "type" : "keyword" }, 
                                     "AccountId" : { "type" : "keyword" }
                         } }, 
                 "Name" :{ type" : "text"}
}}}}

Comment: I have not configured any index template

Comment: Using 7.11.2 version of Elastic search